# HEX to Signed Int confusion

Tags: casting, binary, type-conversion, numbers, hex

I am a tad confused about my problem here..

I am reading a stream of data in HEX from a sensor. It's a scaled representation of degrees of a steering angle.

After consulting the datasheet I found it saying "variable type: int16_t".

So it's a signed int converted into HEX. What confuses me is to how do I go about converting HEX back into signed int?

I am struggling to think of the steps I have to take to achieve that. Isn't HEX always unsigned? Can't I just cast the HEX into int? Aghhh, I am really confused.

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: What language? Most languages have a function that can convert hex to decimal and it’s easy to write yourself. Hexadecimal isn’t always unsigned, it’s whatever you interpret it to be.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, C/C++. What confuses me the most is how they interpret numbers.. For example, 010 in 2's complement is -2. Now, if I write int a = 0b010 and print it, it prints 2.. Why?

Comment: No, binary 010 is 2. The highest bit is zero

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, but I thought every language used 2's complement for signed numbers, so if I do "signed int", wouldn't that use 2's complement?

Comment: It’s not about language. It’s about the platform. But why does this matter? But usually it is 2’s complement, yes. How is that an issue?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen the issue is that I am not sure what I am converting the hex into. For example, imagine there is a 3 value that's been converted into hex. It's 2's complement is 101. 3 in hex is 03. If I convert 03 to binary in C I will always get 011, so I don't see how it uses 2's complement?

Comment: Why do you think its 2’s complement would be 010? It’s still 011, as it has always been.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, I think I am misunderstanding of how 2's complement actually works.. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement the table on the right says 3's 2's complenet is 101.. What am I missing?

Comment: No, it doesn’t. It says -3 is 101. 3 is 011.

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen, okay, I see now.. In that case, how do I know which hex numbers are negative and which is positive? Decimal - 3 im hex is 03, same as decimal 3, and so on..

Comment: -3 in 8bit hexadecimal is 0xfd. 16bit 0xffd. So what exactly is the problem? You take the 16bit hexadecimal number it gives you and convert it into a 16bit value.

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen, the problem is that 0XFD can also be interpreted as 253, so how do I enforce the signedness?

Comment: By making your variable signed. Then it’s interpreted as signed.

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen, I see. So far I had only had positive values even when I know they have to be negative. I will try again when I'm back home but thank you very much for clearing a few things up!